# Modify login page after destroying session due to of inactivity

Tags: php

Does anyone know of a utility or method by which I can have the login page information change when a user is logged out due to inactivity. Currently, after a few miuntes of inactivity I popup a login message and redirect the user to `logout.html`, ((which is a tpl) where the session & cookies are destroyed.

I'm currently using the following for redirecting the user:

```
header("Location: " . $this->site->hosts->manager . 'login.php');
```

After redirection, I would like to display an alert message displaying "Timed out due to inactivity" beneath the login box.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a flag to tell the page why the user was logged out..

```
header("Location: " . $this->site->hosts->manager . 'login.php?reason=timedout');


if (isset($_GET['reason']) && $_GET['reason']=="timedout") { echo 'Your session timed out'; }
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for the existence of `$_GET['reason']` first.  Otherwise you'll get an error if it's not included in the URL.  `if (!empty($_GET['reason']) && $_GET['reason'] == 'timedout') { ... }`

Comment: @curtisdf Good save, haven't used !empty before so I'll play it safe with what I know.

Comment: `isset()` works too.  :-)  It's actually a little more efficient in this case.  `empty()` does an `isset()` internally, along with checking that the value is, er, empty.  ;-)

Comment: @curtisdf So, `!empty()` would fail something like index.php?reason= whereas `isset()` would be true?

Comment: Exactly.  `!empty()` would return `FALSE` in this case, whereas `isset()` would return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your redirect code to attach a parameter to the end of the URL:

```
header("Location: " . $this->site->hosts->manager . 'login.php?e=0');
```

You will then reference this parameter on your `login.php` page by checking if the parameter exists.  If it exists, then notify the user that they were logged out due to inactivity.

```
<?php

$error = (isset($_GET['e']) ? $_GET['e'] : '');
$reasons = array(
    '0' => 'Logged out due to inactivity.',
    '1' => 'Invalid Username/Password.'
    );

if(!empty($error) && $error < count($reasons)){
    echo $reasons[$error];
}
?>
```

The above solution utilizes an array for storing the messages as you can utilize the check for other notifications such as "Invalid username/password".  In addition, it checks to make sure that the value specified is within the bounds of the array.